# Angular material paginator first page work only after click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, paginator

I know there have been several similar questions, but I can't solve the problem. event.pageIndex doesn't work properly on page refresh, it's the simplest thing anyone could ask from a paginator. Load the first page immediately, without having to press the next and previous buttons. I'm new in angular hope that u will help me

This is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="products-container">
        <app-order-item *ngFor="let product of pageSlice" [product]="product" (addItemToCart)="addToCart(product)">
        </app-order-item>
    </div>
    <div class="paginator-container">
        <mat-paginator class="paginator" #paginator
        [length]="this.productsArray.length" 
        [pageSize]="10" 
        [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 50]"
        (page)="onPageChange($event)"
            aria-label="Select page">
        </mat-paginator>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my TypeScript

```
  productsArray: Product[] = [];
  product: Product | undefined
  
  pageSlice = this.productsArray.slice(0, 10)
  


    onPageChange(event: PageEvent) {
      console.log(event);
      console.log(event.pageIndex)
      let startIndex = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
      let endIndex = startIndex + event.pageSize;
      if (endIndex > this.productsArray.length) {
        endIndex = this.productsArray.length;
      }

      this.pageSlice = this.productsArray.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
```

Comment: What does both console print in onPageChange method?

Comment: console.log(event) = {previousPageIndex: 0, pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 10, length: 75}
console.log(event.pageIndex) = 1
I need on load event.pageIndex to be 0